# SQL Server: how to query when and where (which database) logins take a connection?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, logging

I have many databases in one SQL Server instance. Also I have many individual domain users for logins and also domain groups as logins. These logins are attached to databases as database users. Now I would like to create a report (or a query) to find out when and where (which database) these logins take a connection. I tried to find this information from sys-schema, but I could not find this kind of information. Where SQL Server store this information and how to create this kind of report? I would also like to automate this using a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set up a SQL trace logging all login events then just query that.

Answer (score 1):

in the login stored procedure, along with the username, add a GetDate() and DB_NAME() to each record in a table called LoginData (or whatever you prefer)

Comment: if you need me to elaborate on this, let me know. i am at work, and tend to rush answering a bit.